# Laravel 5.3 Route::resource with parameters before the actual resource parameter

Tags: php, laravel, routes, crud

I trying to make this REST design but I am having trouble.

I have a resource called `list`

I want before `/list` it to have a dynamic parameter like so `{username}/list` and the have the CRUD options like edit `{username}/list/{id}/edit` and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `::resource` method you can dictate the hierarchical route pattern by using a `.` between your models, for instance:

```
Route::resource('user.list', 'ListController');
```

This will produce something like this:

```
/user/{user}/list/{list}
```

However you want to have a username - which is fine, we just need to add some explicit model binding in your `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider`

```
Route::bind('user', function($value)(){
    if(is_numeric($value)) {
        return User::find($value);
    } else { 
        return User::where('username', $value)->first();
    }
});
```

Adding this `explicit model binding` will attempt to resolve the user over `dependency injection` first by `ID` if the $value is numeric. If not, then it will attempt to match the value against the username column on the user table.

Hopefully this helps.